# Updating a JLabel within a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jlabel

I've been searching around this site and the internet for hours trying to figure out how to fix this problem. I'm creating a game and it's my first time using graphics. I figured out how to create a JFrame, JPanel and JLabel, and the only problem I can't seem to get around is updating the JLabel. Let's say I start it out like this:

```
JLabel testing = new JLabel ("blah", JLabel.CENTER);
testing.setAlignmentX(0);
testing.setAlignmentY(0);
frame.add(testing);
```

I am able to change the text after a `Thread.sleep(2500)` by using `testing.setText("hi");`, but the previous state of the JLabel (which says blah) is still there. The "hi" just appears on top. I've tried `testing.setVisible(false);`, and so many other things but nothing is letting me display the JLabel, hide it, and then change it.

Any ideas what could be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `setText` should work as you intended it; there must be some other problem. Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Take a look at [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for a better understanding how the Swing API works and why you are having issues. See [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for one possible solution

Comment: @OhleC (String test is static in class) ```public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wong & Irwin Are Cool");
  ISU panel = new ISU();
  frame.add(panel);
  frame.setResizable (false);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setLocation(350, 50);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  JLabel testing = new JLabel (test, JLabel.CENTER);
  testing.setAlignmentX(0);
  testing.setAlignmentY(0);
  frame.add(testing);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  testing.setVisible(false);
  test = "hi";
  testing.setText(test);```

Comment: @OhleC Yikes that didnt come out very well. I hope you can read it okay. ISU is the class name

Comment: @OhleC ```public ISU() {
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension (600, 600));
 }```

Comment: Please edit your question and the necessary code and explanations. The comments are for short questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `sleep` or otherwise block on the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Use `javax.swing.Timer` instead. Note: not any other class of the same name in a different package.

```
            javax.swing.Timer timer =
                new javax.swing.Timer(2500, event -> {
                    testing.setText("hi");
                });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
```